# No persistence provider for EntityManager named testPU

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, entitymanager

I'm developing a small application on JBoss 7.1.0 using Guice as DI Framework and I'm building it using maven. 
All my DAO's get the EntityManager injected as constructor Injection:

```
public class MyDao{
...
@Inject
public MyDao(EntityManager em){}
...
}
```

To test these classes I need to create an EntityManager in my tests.

To create the EntityManager I added my persistence.xml to
src/test/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml

My persistence.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.foo.Foo</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:unit-testing-jpa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

In my setup method of the tests I do the following:

```
private EntityManager em;

@Before
public void setup() {
    em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU")
            .createEntityManager();
}
```

But I always get the error "No persistence provider for EntityManager named testPU". (Running the tests in eclipse and using maven)

I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. Can you please help me?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency with scope `provided` or `test` (I need more info about project to determine scope)

```
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>...</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```

PS. It's only for JBoss. For example, for WebLogic scope should be `compile`

Comment: Does it really need to be `compile` for WebLogic? If you're using Hibernate through the JPA API, you should only ever need the API on the compile classpath. And if we're looking at unit tests here, then the container used at runtime shouldn't have any influence.

Comment: That was exactly what was missing! THX for the answer! I had to add slf4j additionaly: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.6</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>